# Cordova IOS webview interface is randomly unresponsive

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I'm building an app using Cordova 7.10 for IOS 10 & 11.

From time to time, very randomly, the app seems to not fire any touch event, like a freeze.   But it's not a freeze, as the javascript part is still working fine - checked inspecting it with Safari and running some code and showing some alert windows. After some time, the interface is responsive again.

I've added the content-security-policy meta tag as stated here [Cordova app hanging during startup on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10) but no success so far, the random "freeze" is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing this issue on iOS 11.3/11.4, then it may due to a bug in those versions of iOS which leads to event timestamps becoming negative and causes some touch event handling libraries to fail to handle the touch event.

For more info:

- [Why mobile Safari touchEvents have negative timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49920582/777265)
- https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/549

Note: the bug is fixed in iOS 12